# sizeof(MPI_INT) different from sizeof(int)

Tags: types, parallel-processing, size, mpi

I noticed that the sized of the int and double are different that the ones that are calculated using the function MPI_Type_size(MPI_INT, &MPI_INT_SIZE); Does that mean sizeof(MPI_INT) returns the wrong value of 8?? which it should normally be 4 
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`MPI_INT` is an MPI **type handle**. It is used to tell MPI to treat the memory content as `int` when reading while sending a message or writing while receiving a message. It is **not** a language data type and cannot be used to declare variables. Using the *size-of* operator on an MPI handle is wrong as it gives the size of the handle itself and not the size of the underlying datatype. MPI handles are either integer indexes into some table of MPI objects, in which case the *size-of* that handle will be `sizeof(int)`, or a pointer to an opaque data structure, in which case the *size-of* will be `sizeof(void *)`. On a typical LP64 system that will be 4 bytes and 8 bytes respectively.

The same applies to every other predefined MPI datatype handle, such as `MPI_FLOAT`, `MPI_DOUBLE`, `MPI_CHAR`, and so on.