# MPI in C++ datatypes misunderstandings

Tags: c++, types, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

I developed a C++ code which uses MPI. I compile with C++17.

I am trying to use MPI-IO to save the data to disk at the end of the program.

I realized that I am not using MPI-IO correctly, as the data values I load from the saved file are all 0 + I * 0 (complex numbers, in double precision).

Trying to debug, I printed the following (thinking that I do not use the MPI - Datatypes correctly):

```
std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": sizeof(std::complex<double>) = " << sizeof(std::complex<double>) << ", and sizeof(MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX) = " << sizeof(MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX) << std::endl;
std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": sizeof(std::complex<double>) = " << sizeof(std::complex<double>) << ", and sizeof(MPI::DOUBLE_COMPLEX) = " << sizeof(MPI::DOUBLE_COMPLEX) << std::endl;
```

It prints (without loss of generality, from rank 1):

```
rank 1: sizeof(std::complex<double>) = 16, and sizeof(MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX) = 8
rank 1: sizeof(std::complex<double>) = 16, and sizeof(MPI::DOUBLE_COMPLEX) = 16
```

This is rather strange for me.

The buffer I want to save to disk of defined as `std::complex<double> * buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices = new std::complex<double> [num_elems];`.

**I save it as below:**

```
// Parallel MPI-IO to save to disk
// ************************************
MPI_Status status;
MPI_File fh;

MPI_error_value = MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,    "Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat",   (MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY),   MPI_INFO_NULL,      &fh);
if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_open`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we opened the file!" << std::endl;

// Each rank writes ( num_elems ) std::complex<double> elements to file
// rank 0 writes the first ( num_elems ) elements, rank 1 writes the next num_elems elements, etc ...

// Set the view of each rank

// disp shall be in BYTES
MPI_Offset disp = MPI_Offset(rank) * (num_elems) * sizeof(std::complex<double>) ;

MPI_error_value = MPI_File_set_view(fh,        disp,        MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,  MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,    "external32", MPI_INFO_NULL);

if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_set_view`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we set the view on the file!" << std::endl;


MPI_error_value = MPI_File_write_all(fh,           &buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[0],   (num_elems),     MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,       &status);

if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_write_all`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we wrote_all in the file!" << std::endl;

MPI_error_value = MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); // TODO: needed here or not ?

if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_Barrier`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
}    
std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we applied the BARRIER!" << std::endl;


MPI_error_value = MPI_File_close(&fh);

if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_close`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we closed in the file!" << std::endl;


std::cout << "From rank " << rank << " we are MPI_Finalize()-ing ! " << std::endl;
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
```

**This does not produce the results I expect when I read the file in another `.cpp` as below**:

```
MPI_Status status;
MPI_File fh;
int MPI_error_value;

MPI_error_value = MPI_File_open(      MPI_COMM_WORLD, "../../build_dir_64nodes/Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat",  MPI_MODE_RDONLY,     MPI_INFO_NULL,        &fh);
if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_open`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we opened the file" << std::endl;

MPI_Offset disp = MPI_Offset(rank) * ( num_elems ) * sizeof(std::complex<double>);
std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we have the disp = " << disp << std::endl;


MPI_error_value = MPI_File_set_view(         fh,               disp,      MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,  MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,    "external32",                MPI_INFO_NULL);
if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_set_view`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we have set the file_view" << std::endl;


MPI_error_value = MPI_File_read_all(        fh,        &Psi_grid_for_this_proc[0],  ( num_elems ),   MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,       &status);
if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_read_all`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we read_all" << std::endl;
```

**My first question is: what MPI datatype shall I use for saving a `std::complex<double>` array in a .cpp program to disk using MPI-IO, and then read it?**

I am confused about the MPI datatypes and their C++ equivalent.

**My second question is: is the above procedure of setting the view of each rank as:**

```
MPI_Offset disp = MPI_Offset(rank) * (num_elems) * sizeof(std::complex<double>) ;
MPI_error_value = MPI_File_set_view(fh,        disp,        MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,  MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,    "external32", MPI_INFO_NULL);
```

then saving the buffer of each rank as:

```
MPI_error_value = MPI_File_write_all(fh,           &buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[0],   (num_elems),     MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,       &status);
```

correct?

Do I actually perform what I envision to do?

**Another question which arises from these considerations would be what datatype I shall use in `MPI_Alltoall()` calls which distribute the `buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices` array between ranks?**

I am now doing it as below, but after these investigations I am thinking it's wrong (illustrative call, just to show the datatypes):

```
MPI_Alltoall(  
                &vec_for_ALLTOALL[0],               (num_of_is_req * num_of_LM_pairs),    MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,   
                &buffer_for_Psi_spec_i_slices[0],   (num_of_is_req * num_of_LM_pairs),    MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,     MPI_COMM_WORLD
            );
```

Thank you!

PS: I have tried a simple saving-to-disk-4-C++-ints program and ran it on 2 processes and then inspect the saved-binary with `$ od -f` and I fail with that as well!

I think the problem is that `sizeof(int) != sizeof(MPI_INT)` (checked) and thus I do not have a match between the C++ datatype I am trying to save (a plain int) and the MPI - Datatype I write.

On the machine I am testing, I compile with `$mpiCC -O3 test.cpp -o test.x` then run it as : `$mpirun -np 2 ./test.x`

***EDIT: how I write the simple save 4 ints to disk program run on 2 processes (a MWE for testing) ***:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

#include <mpi.h>

const std::complex<double> I(0.0, 1.0); // imaginary unit, I*I = -1


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int rank; // the "ID" of this MPI process 
    int size; // total no of MPI processes

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int * buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices = new int [2];

    buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[0] = rank + 3;
    buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[1] = rank + 5;


    int to_return;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_File fh;
    int MPI_error_value;


    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,    "Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat",   (MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY),   MPI_INFO_NULL,      &fh);
    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_open`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we opened the file!" << std::endl;

    // disp shall be in BYTES
    MPI_Offset disp = MPI_Offset(rank) * (2) * sizeof(int) ;

    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_set_view(fh,        disp,         MPI_INT,  MPI_INT,    "native",        MPI_INFO_NULL);

    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_set_view`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we set the view on the file!" << std::endl;


    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_write_all(fh,           &buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[0],          (2),                                 MPI_INT,         &status);
    
    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_write_all`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we wrote_all in the file!" << std::endl;

    MPI_error_value = MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); // TODO: needed here or not ?
    
    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_Barrier`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }    
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we applied the BARRIER!" << std::endl;

    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_close(&fh);
    
    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_close`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

This produces a file which when inspected with `$ od -f Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat` prints:

```
0000000           4e-45           7e-45           6e-45           8e-45
0000020
```

Comment: did you really try `sizeof(MPI_INT)` or did you `MPI_Type_size(MPI_INT, ...)` ?
the former is incorrect (`MPI_Datatype` is an opaque handler), the latter is how to do it.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, I tried ``sizeof(MPI_INT)`` , the first of your versions. I will try to see what your second approach prints now (i.e. the ``MPI_Type_size(MPI_INT, ...)``). Edit: I have found this ``https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554429/sizeofmpi-int-different-from-sizeofint`` now and I see what you mean.

Comment: `sizeof(MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX)` likely gives you `sizeof(void*)` or `sizeof(double*)`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, I have checked with ``MPI_Type_size(MPI_INT, &to_return)`` where ``to_return`` is an int declared previously on the stack, and then I print ``to_return``, and it prints the exact same value as ``sizeof(int)`` prints on my machine, both printing 4. Similarly with ``MPI_C_COMPLEX_DOUBLE`` and ``std::complex<double>``, your procedure prints ``to_return = 16``

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, can you please see the update to the question, in which I present my MWE for writing 4 ``ints`` to a ``.dat`` file and then inspecting with ``od -f``?

Comment: sure, what do you expect by writing `MPI_INT` and reading (single precision) `float`?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, thank you. I understand thus that to read C++ ints I need to use ``od -d`` ?

Comment: I think `-i` or `-t dI` instead. double check the man page on your system.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, none of those options produce at least reasonably ints when they output in the console. Please, can you see this MWE I post here detailing this writing to disk simple exercise? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77037051/mpi-io-writing-to-disk-with-mpi-file-write-at-all-or-mpi-file-write-all-misunder! Thank you!

Comment: Also, if anyone can post an answer to this question s.t. I can close it (or shall I delete it, as the answer seems to have been written here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554429/sizeofmpi-int-different-from-sizeofint ). Thanks a lot