# MPI-IO writing to disk with MPI_File_write_at_all or MPI_File_write_all misunderstandings?

Tags: c++, file, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

I am trying to write data to disk from a buffer in C++ using MPI-IO.

For concretness and MWE, each rank holds 2 ints in its buffer.
I want that rank 0 writes its 2 elements in the file first occupying 2 ints, then rank 1 writes its 2 elements in the file second occupying the next 2 ints from the file.

I gather that I can do this in 2 ways (a hard constraint I impose is that I use collective calls):

1. Set a file view (different on each process) and the use `MPI_File_write_all(...)`
2. Use from the start `MPI_File_write_at_all(...)`

In my MWEs, I tried both approaches.

I firstly present 2) and show what I get:

**Method 2): write**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

#include <mpi.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int rank; // the "ID" of this MPI process 
    int size; // total no of MPI processes

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int * buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices = new int [2];

    buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[0] = rank + 3; // rank 0 has 3, rank 1 has 4
    buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[1] = rank + 5; // rank 0 has 5, rank 1 has 6
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << " has Psi[0] = " << buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[0] << " and Psi[1] = " << buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[1] << std::endl;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_File fh;
    int MPI_error_value;

    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,    "Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat",   (MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY),   MPI_INFO_NULL,      &fh);
    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_open`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we opened the file!" << std::endl;

    MPI_Offset offset = MPI_Offset(rank) * 2; // in which units is this? A: in ``etype`` units
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": offset = " << offset << std::endl;
    
    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_write_at_all(fh, offset, &buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[0], 2, MPI_INT, &status);

    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_write_all`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we wrote_all in the file!" << std::endl;

    MPI_error_value = MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); // TODO: needed here or not ?
    
    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_Barrier`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }    
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we applied the BARRIER!" << std::endl;

    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_close(&fh);
    
    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_close`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

This produces a file called `Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat` which when inspected with `$ od -i Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat` outputs:

```
0000000      262147      393216           0
0000012
```

Doing `$ od -d Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat` I get:

```
0000000     3     4     0     6     0
0000012
```

Reasonably close, but now what I want.

**I was expecting to obtain the linear file to be: `3 5 4 6`. That is my aim.**

Q: How could I possibly obtain this using the method 2) above?

For completeness, I post my attempt to obtain this output using the method 1).

While I do obtain the output from `od -i Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat` to be what I expect, I cannot read the file's contents in another .cpp, which I detail:

**Method 1): writing:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int rank; // the "ID" of this MPI process 
    int size; // total no of MPI processes

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int * buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices = new int [2];

    buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[0] = rank + 3; // rank 0 has 3, rank 1 has 4
    buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[1] = rank + 5; // rank 0 has 5, rank 1 has 6
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << " has Psi[0] = " << buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[0] << " and Psi[1] = " << buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[1] << std::endl;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_File fh;
    int MPI_error_value;

    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,    "Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat",   (MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY),   MPI_INFO_NULL,      &fh);
    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_open`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we opened the file!" << std::endl;

    // disp shall be in BYTES
    MPI_Offset disp = MPI_Offset(rank) * (2) * sizeof(int);

    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_set_view(fh,        disp,         MPI_INT,  MPI_INT,    "native",        MPI_INFO_NULL);

    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_set_view`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we set the view on the file!" << std::endl;

    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_write_all(fh,           &buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[0],          (2),                                 MPI_INT,         &status);

    MPI_error_value = MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); // TODO: needed here or not ?

    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_close(&fh);
    
    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_close`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

**Method 1): reading and failure:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

#include <mpi.h>



int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int rank; // the "ID" of this MPI process 
    int size; // total no of MPI processes

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int * buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices = new int [2];

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_File fh;
    int MPI_error_value;

    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,    "Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat",   (MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY),   MPI_INFO_NULL,      &fh);
    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_open`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we opened the file!" << std::endl;

    MPI_Offset disp = MPI_Offset(rank) * (2) * sizeof(int);

    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_set_view(fh,        disp,        MPI_INT,  MPI_INT,    "native",  MPI_INFO_NULL);

    
    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_read_all(        fh,        &buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[0],  (2),   MPI_INT,       &status);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": Psi_grid[i] for i = " << i << " = " << buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[i] << std::endl;
    }

    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_close(&fh);
    
    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_close`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;

}
```

This produces an output of:

```
rank 0: we opened the file!
rank 0: Psi_grid[i] for i = 0 = 341273760
rank 0: Psi_grid[i] for i = 1 = 32595
rank 1: we opened the file!
rank 1: Psi_grid[i] for i = 0 = -27030512
rank 1: Psi_grid[i] for i = 1 = 32541
```

Totally wrong! Even though in the terminal, the command `$ od -i Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat` on the output from method 1)'s writing
logic produces correct results:

```
0000000           3           5           4           6
0000020
```

**EDIT** :

With your help, I managed to make the method with `MPI_File_write_at_all(...)` to be able to produce a file which when inspected with `od -d` produces:

```
od -d Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat 
0000000     3     0     5     0     4     0     6     0
0000020
```

I am now posting the reading `.cpp` with `MPI_File_read_at_all()`, which still doesn't populate the buffer with the values I would expect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

#include <mpi.h>
 
int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int rank; // the "ID" of this MPI process 
    int size; // total no of MPI processes

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int * buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices = new int [2];

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_File fh;
    int MPI_error_value;


    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,    "Psi_grid_from_all_ranks.dat",   (MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY),   MPI_INFO_NULL,      &fh);
    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_open`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": we opened the file!" << std::endl;



    
    MPI_Offset offset = MPI_Offset(rank) * 2 * sizeof(int);

    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_read_at_all(fh, offset, &buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[0], 2, MPI_INT, &status);
    

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": Psi_grid[i] for i = " << i << " = " << buffer_for_Psi_grid_i_slices[i] << std::endl;
    }

    MPI_error_value = MPI_File_close(&fh);
    
    if (MPI_error_value != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "rank " << rank << ": ERROR in ``MPI_File_close`` with value = " << MPI_error_value << std::endl;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;

}
```

This produces:

```
mpirun -np 2 debug_MPI_read.x
rank 0: we opened the file!
rank 0: Psi_grid[i] for i = 0 = 1031781536
rank 0: Psi_grid[i] for i = 1 = 32566
rank 1: we opened the file!
rank 1: Psi_grid[i] for i = 0 = 1931947024
rank 1: Psi_grid[i] for i = 1 = 32669
```

Comment: You forgot `MPI_File_set_view()`, so your offset is in bytes and should be multiplied by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, thank you for trying to help and your patience. I still don't get it. If I use ``MPI_File_write_at_all()``, my method 2),  don't I explicitly tell the computer to write the data AT some specific points in the file, using the ``offset`` argument? Do I need to set a view when using ``write_at``? If I set the view, then the ``at`` thing doesn't specify a point relative to the view? In my method 2) above, I want ``at`` to specify a location in the file relative to the 0-th byte.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, I think I understood what you say and I got it for method 2) (i.e. the first code snippets I posted). Please bear with me for a bit.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, while the writing with ``MPI_File_write_at()`` works when the file is inspected by``od``, I cannot read in another ``.cpp`` the contents of the file. Please see the ``EDIT`` part at the end of the question if you still have time. Thanks

Comment: do not open your file write only if you are only reading it later!

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, amazing, thank you! Very well spotted error!